# ¿Como valido que se ingrese una categoría existente con eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hola estoy haciendo un crud de productos.
Los productos cuentan con los campos: name,slug,price,category_id y status.
Cuando pongo un category_id que no existe en la base de datos, me tira error por la clave foranea.
¿Cómo valido eso desde el form request? Para que el programa no se rompa.

-- Este es mi FormRequest--

public function rules()

```
{
    $product = $this->route()->parameter('product');

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:products,slug', 
        'status' => 'required|in:1,2',
        'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
    ];

    if($product){
        $rules['slug'] = 'required|unique:products,slug,' . $product->id;
    }

    if($this->status==2){
        $rules = array_merge($rules,[
            'category_id' => 'required', //LA DUDA ESTA EN ESTA LINEA
        ]);       
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: el concepto esta mal; el `category_id` no debe ser un campo debe ser un `select` de los `category_id` y `category_name`  que ya existen y debe ser required ... con eso aseguras que el usuario solo tome la categoría de producto que existe.

Comment: Claro, eso hago. Lo que pasa es que estoy probando validar lo mas que pueda. Intento validar que no se ingrese cualquier dato desde el codigo html de la pagina.

Comment: ok entonces en tu controlador debes hacer un control que valide si el categori id existe o no ... tal cual un pinche select a la base de datos ... peroooo si no existe debes detener la ejecución y mandar un mensaje de que la categoría indicada no existe ...

Comment: desconosco si laravel y eloquent cuentan con un output para errores de ese tipo...

Comment: en mi caso implemente algo así: https://i.imgur.com/7GPYqpZ.png

Comment: oh bueno, gracias!!

Comment: Estuve buscando y funciona haciendo esto:
'category_id' => 'required|exists:App\Models\Category,id',

Comment: incluso eso lo uso en desarrollo por que muestro datos de donde se detecto el error ... pero en producción lo que hago es mostrare un código de timestamp y creo un log de errores pero le mando un mensaje de error al usuario ... de tal manera que si me envían una captura o el código timestamp poder ubicar el error del sistema ...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la regla `exists:table,column`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists

```
 if($this->status==2){
        $rules = array_merge($rules,[
            'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id',
        ]);       
    }
```